# How to generate a random star using turtle graphics in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, turtle-graphics

I'm new to turtle graphics in Python, and I'm running into some issues with a particular problem. I'm trying to generate a star that uses a `while` loop to draw random jagged lines from the center of a circle.

Each line should have a distance of 250. I'm using the `penup` `pendown` and `setpos` commands within the loop to draw these random lines, and each line should be a random color.

Here's an idea of what I'm hoping to generate: [random star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4cmi.png)

Here's the code I have so far:

```
# tg_random_star.py

from random import randrange
from turtle import *

MAX_ANGLE = 30

def jaggedLine(turtle, pieces, pieceLength):

    for i in range(pieces):
        turtle.forward(pieceLength)
        r = randrange(-MAX_ANGLE, MAX_ANGLE + 1)
        turtle.right(r)

def jumpToCenter(turtle):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(0, 0)
    turtle.pendown()

def randomColor(turtle):
    turtle.colormode(255)
    r = randrange(255)    # red component of color
    g = randrange(255)    # green component
    b = randrange(255)    # blue component

    turtle.pencolor(r, g, b)

def main():
    colormode(255)
    t = Turtle()
    jaggedLine(t, 10, 30)
    jumpToCenter(t)
    jaggedLine(t, 10, 30)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It currently generates 2 lines, but the `turtle.pencolor(r, g, b)` and the `colormode(255)` don't seem to be working, as both lines are black. Any idea why these lines aren't in color?

Rather than using `for i in range(pieces)` to draw lines that are based on the number of segments, how can I use a `while` loop to draw jagged lines that each have a distance of 250? In other words, I want each line to have a distance of 250 before drawing a new line from the center.

(Maybe I could use the `xcor` and `ycor` methods to find the turtle’s position, then calculate the distance using the distance formula?)

```
def distance(p0, p1):
return math.sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p0[1] - p1[1])**2)`
```

Any help or explanation would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea why these lines aren't in color?

That one's easy, it's because you never actually call `randomColor()`

> Rather than using for i in range(pieces) to draw lines that are based
>   on the number of segments, how can I use a while loop to draw jagged
>   lines that each have a distance of 250?

Here we can take advantage of the under utilized `.distance()` method of turtle to tell us how far we are from center.  This is straight line distance, not path travelled distance, which seems to match your target illustration:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randrange

MAX_ANGLE = 30
MAX_DISTANCE = 250

def jaggedLine(t, pieceLength):
    randomColor(t)

    while t.distance(0, 0) < MAX_DISTANCE:
        angle = randrange(-MAX_ANGLE, MAX_ANGLE + 1)
        t.right(angle)
        t.forward(pieceLength)

def jumpToCenter(t):
    t.penup()
    t.home()  # return turtle to original position
    t.pendown()

def randomColor(t):
    # red, green & blue components of turtle color
    r, g, b = randrange(255), randrange(255), randrange(255)

    t.pencolor(r, g, b)

def main():
    screen = Screen()
    screen.tracer(False)  # because I have no patience
    screen.colormode(255)

    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.pensize(2)

    for angle in range(0, 360, 2):
        jumpToCenter(turtle)
        turtle.setheading(angle)
        jaggedLine(turtle, 30)

    screen.tracer(True)  # forces an update
    screen.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Reworked some of the code based on suggestions by @AnnZen